# Implementation of classical control of multi-qubits gates multiple times

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I am implementing classical control of gates multiple times. There is no issue if the gate is a local gate, such as an $X$ gate. However, it seems that if I append the control multi-qubits gates more than once, the control classical registers will all become the latest one, as shown in the circuit diagram below. Although I append the first gate with `c_if(0, 1)`, after `append c_if(1, 1)`, the control classical register of the first gate changed from `c_0` to `c_1`. May I ask how to solve this issue?

```python
qc = QuantumCircuit(3, 6)
gate = UnitaryGate(identity_matrix)

qc.append(gate, [0, 1, 2]).c_if(0, 1)
qc.append(gate, [0, 1, 2]).c_if(1, 1)
```

[image: Implementation of classical control of multi-qubit gates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug. You can report it [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues).

You can avoid this issue by using [`IfElseOp`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.IfElseOp) which is a more flexible replacement for `c_if`.

```
with qc.if_test((0, 1)):
    qc.append(gate, [0, 1, 2])

with qc.if_test((1, 1)):
    qc.append(gate, [0, 1, 2])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It has been very helpful. However, may I ask how you change the appearance of your control gates? It looks much nicer than the default appearance in qiskit. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using `qc.draw('mpl', style='textbook')` to draw a circuit